# Как запретить Dialog исчезать после нажатия за его пределами

Tags: android, android-dialog

При показе окна `Dialog` требуется запретить закрывать его нажатием на экран за его границами, предложив таким образом воспользоваться вариантом в виде, к примеру, кнопки.

Как запретить Dialog исчезать после нажатия за его пределами?

Comment: А зачем это вообще делать?) Это ведь нестандартное поведение в android'e.

Comment: @Morozov: у меня после такого закрытия (за границами Диалога) почему-то открывается стартовое Активити, а не то, откуда был вызван Диалог.

Comment: Ну это уже в Вашем коде какой то баг) возможно Вы вешаете куда то ещё onClickListener(). Но опять же, так это не работает.

Comment: @Morozov, вот так вот баги становятся фичами :D

Comment: @Flippy я тут подумал, возмоОожно это имеет место быть, когда ты пользователю показываешь какой то диалог с принятием соглашения например, но тоже, сомнительная движуха всё таки)

Comment: @Morozov, в настройках сети есть "Роуминг" (это пример) там если поставить чекбокс то он сначала ставится а потом показывается окно с подтверждением, так вот если окно закрыть, то чекбокс снимается. Думаю в этом случае так правильнее.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

То же самое из кода:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Запретить закрывать диалог по кнопке Back:

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

В стилях к Диалогу добавить пункт.

```
<style name="MyStyleDialog" parent="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>
```